# SonarQube with mixed .NET and Angular Projects

Tags: c#, .net, angular, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am new to SonarQube. My goal is to set up SonarQube to scan a .NET Solution with mixed content - Some Projects are using C# and one is written in TS/Angular. The Project structure looks like this:

[image: Project Structure]

Now I am using the SonarScanner .NET to analyze my project. The problem is, that the C# code gets analyzed, but not the Angular code.

My sonar-project.properties looks like this (the Solution is actually inside the folder ./src/):

```
sonar.projectKey=it-entwicklung_dotnet_mypoettinger_AYFcAof9yGNGEq-TtfGV
sonar.qualitygate.wait=true
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.projectName=mypoettinger
sonar.sources=src/
```

Inside the scanner process i am getting the follwing message:

```
/builds/it-entwicklung/dotnet/xxx/src/xxx.App/xxx.App.esproj : warning NU1503: Skipping restore for project '/builds/it-entwicklung/dotnet/xxx/src/xxx.App/xxx.App.esproj'. The project file may be invalid or missing targets required for restore. [/builds/it-entwicklung/dotnet/xxx/src/xxx.sln]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: xxx.App.esproj?

Comment: What do you mean? I am sorry, but I don't know what you are trying to tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nothing.**

You are doing nothing wrong. JavaScript/TypeScript projects are not supported by NuGet restore, and you can ignore the warning, as stated by [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1503).